# Jquery cycle plugin

Tags: jquery, asp.net-3.5, jquery-cycle

I am using jquery cycle to show images as slides. How to scroll two images at a time without using any button.

Code:

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {            
        $('#album').cycle({
            fx: 'scrollHorz',               
            speed: 1000,
            timeout: 0, continuous: true,
            pause: 0, sync: 1
        });
    });
```

Geetha.

Comment: Please specify your question. No clue what you are talking about ^^

Comment: i am having set of images. i want to scroll two images as a set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not quite sure if I understood you correct, but maybe you mean something like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="album1" class="cycle">
    <img src="1.png" alt="" />
    <img src="2.png" alt="" />
    ...
</div>
<div id="album2" class="cycle">
    <img src="3.png" alt="" />
    <img src="4.png" alt="" />
    ...
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {            
    $('.cycle').cycle({
        fx: 'scrollHorz',               
        speed: 1000,
        timeout: 0, 
        continuous: true,
        pause: 0, 
        sync: 1
    });
});
```

?